# Can we add observer to @Endpoint in Java Tyrus websocket API

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

I want to add observer to @Endpoint so that other classes can be notified for events like @OnMessage.

Can we do that for @Endpoint?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried using Observer pattern, but it was unable to notify observer for @OnMessage event.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you used?

Comment: Well...
I changed the code.

Comment: @PavelBucek,

My requirement is as below:
I want to add some kind of observer or callback for my Endpoint class.
Whenever Endpoint gets any message, Observer class will get notification for it. Generally we can add some code in OnMessage method to notify other class about event like below example:

public void OnMessage(String message){

   ToOtherClass.actOnMessage(message);
}

But I dont want to do any change inside OnMessage. Whenever OnMessage get called by Tyrus API, i must get notification for it.
Suggest some ideas for solution.